# Draw on Canvas created with Scene builder

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently trying to create a small programm with Javafx. The UI is created with Scene builder. I now want to draw on a Canvas i have placed in the middle of the layout. I tried many things for example the code shown below. But nothing is ever drawn. How could i do this? And if i want to redraw the thing i have drawn on it, how could i do that?

*Controller.java*

```java
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Canvas canvas;

    public void createGrid(){
        GraphicsContext g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        g.rect(100,100,300,300);
    }

}
```

*Main.java*

```java
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("layout.fxml"));
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();


        primaryStage.setTitle("Pathfinding");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();


        Controller controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        controller.createGrid();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try either `g.strokeRect(...)` or `g.fillRect(...)` instead of `g.rect()`, depending on what you actually want to do. (Or call either `g.stroke()` or `g.fill()` after calling `g.rect(...)`.)

Comment: Oh my god you are right. This is actually drawing something